# How to style Commerce Order Notification Mail?

Tags: commerce, emails, theming

I'm using the latest version of Commerce kickstart. For order notification I'm using the provided message type together with rules for triggering. Everything works fine and the mails are sent with intended content, but I don't now how to style the mails. I tried to copy mail.css into my theme directory and modified it with my custom styles, but without effect.

Thanks for your hints!